# square wave frequency representation

Tags: filtering, signal-processing, fft, frequency-analysis

New to this signals stuff and i'm confused about the frequency representation of the square wave. Correct me if i'm wrong, a periodic square wave is composed of odd harmonics sine waves which are multiples of the fundamental frequency,  In the frequency domain this just represents decreasing impulses at every odd multiple of the fundamental frequency . 
What relation does the sinc function have with the square wave? and which is the correct spectral representation of the square wave? Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming of signal processing implementations, and would be more appropriate for [dsp.stackexchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing periodic signal and non-periodic signal.

A **periodic signal** can  be represented by a discrete sum of sine wave, which will give you a set of impulse in the frequency domain. This is a **Fourier series**.

A **non-periodic signal** can be represented by a continuous sum of sine wave (integral) which will give you a continuous function in the frequency domain. This is a **Fourier Transform**.

A square wave, which is periodic, can be represented by a series of impulses in the frequency domain.

A square impulse in the time domain (rectangle function) is represented by the sinc(x) function in the frequency domain.